# Address of address of a array

Tags: arrays, c++11, pointers

The following code on execution gives output as '6'.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int a[]={7,5,3,4,1,6};
        int *ptr=(int*)(&a+1);
        printf("%d",*(ptr-1));
        return (0);
}
```

I cannot understand what does the line part "(int*)(&a+1)" mean.

Comment: It means "I don't fear undefined behaviour. I throw in casts until it compiles." Not something you should ever do.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of `6` `int`.    `&a` is therefore of type "pointer to array of `6` `int`" or (in C++ syntax)  `int (*)[6]`.

`&a + 1` is therefore the address of a (non-existent) array of `6` `int` that is in memory immediately past the end of `a`.

`(int *)(&a + 1)` converts the value of `&a + 1` so it has type `int *`.   This gives the address of a single `int` that is in memory immediately past the end of `a`.    Formally `&a + 1` and `(int *)(&a + 1)` have the same VALUE, but different type.

`ptr - 1` therefore gives the address of the last element of `a`, and printing `*(ptr - 1)` therefore gives the value `6`   (which is the value of the last element of `a`).

Comment: But isn't 'a' itself a pointer/address? If it is then what does address of a pointer mean?

Comment: No.  `a` is an array.   A pointer is a variable that contains an address.  Some - but not all - operations give the same result on an "array of X" and a "pointer to X" (where X is a type) but that does not mean "an array is a pointer", nor does it mean "a pointer is an array".

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you draw it out:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
| 7 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 6 | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
^                   ^   ^
|                   |   |
&a                  |   &a + 1
                    |   |
                    |   ptr
                    |
                    ptr - 1
```

That is, the pointer you get from `&a + 1` is pointing *beyond* the end of the array.

Another thing that is good to know is that for any pointer (or array) `ptr` and index `i`, the expression `*(ptr + i)` is equal to `ptr[i]`. So when you do `(*ptr - 1)` you are really doing `ptr[-1]` which happens to be the `6`, the element before `ptr[0]`.